# Visual Studio vertical color bars on the right side margin

Tags: visual-studio

What is the meaning of different color bars on the right side (scroll bar side) on the visual studio?

[image]

Comment: This looks to me like the enhanced scroll bar feature, introduced with [Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2014/01/21/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-enhanced-scroll-bar.aspx), except that the colors are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Version control markers, do you have your code from a source control repo?

It indicates lines that have changed in your local file, if they are unsaved/saved and if they are new.

Can be depandant on additions to your environment, are you using any plugins (as these can use markers in the GUI) like:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cf49cf30-2ca6-4ea0-b7cc-6a8e0dadc1a8

Comment: Yes, I have code from source control. Can you give more explanation of this feature like what do the different colors indicate, like green means what, purple means what?

Comment: Updated original post