# What do the grey marks in the Visual Studio Scroll Bars indicate?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2013 added color indicators to the vertical Scroll Bar and provided [a somewhat helpful legend in the introductory page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudiouk/2013/08/13/visual-studio-2013-enhanced-scrollbar/). And, other questions on this site have asked about [the general meaning of the colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/973598/393280), and about [particular, less common colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35361774/393280). But, having upgraded to Visual Studio 2017, now I see new grey marks on the scrollbar and I am having a difficult time determining their pattern and significance.

[image: Visual Studio Vertical Scroll Bar with unknown marks]

I know the red marks indicates an error, the yellow mark indicates a change, and the thicker, darker grey mark indicates the scroll position. Those lighter grey marks don't align with classes, properties, or anything else I can tell.

Comment: Yes, I have mixed the American spelling of colour with the British spelling for gray. Hope you can cope.

Comment: I cant see from your image but are they blocks of code by any chance?

Comment: Within the scrollbar annotations they fall under the category "errors". No idea why.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They show the locations of suggestions for code fixes.

For example, in one of my projects, I have one showing me where it is suggesting a second class in the file can be pulled out into its own separate file.

(Note the 3 little grey dots under the `A` in `AssertionExtensions`)

You can see the suggestion by either using Ctrl+. or clicking the light bulb icon on the left.

[image: Code fix in Visual Studio]

Comment: And the obvious next question: Any way to turn them off?

Comment: Within Visual Studio, go to Tools >> Options. Under Text Editor > All Languages > Scroll Bars, you'll want the options under Show annotations over vertical scroll bar.

Comment: That would disable all annotations, but I would want to only suppress the suggestion indicators (the grey markers). This could make its own SO question, and if I ever ask it, I'll make sure to add a link here.

Comment: The complete reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-track-your-code-by-customizing-the-scrollbar?view=vs-2022#table-of-annotations

Comment: @palswim Here is how to turn it off: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620794/how-to-hide-grey-dots-on-scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

I would add a related point, that there is also second kind of grey marks, slightly lighter and a bit to the right.
These are **bookmarks**.

[image]